# Processing: Confusion with UnHex, is there an easier way?

Tags: processing

Doing a uni assignment that requires the importing of table data and conversion of numbers into hexadecimal number.
I tried using unHex() but it got quite confusing converting the strings.
Is there an easier way to convert them?

This is a screenshot of the table data:

[image: table data]

```java
Table table;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
 background(255);
  table = loadTable("msfw15.csv", "header");



}

void draw() {
  //Getting tags, probably an easier way.
  String work = table.getString(0, 1);
  String fashion = table.getString(1, 1);
  String blogger = table.getString(2, 1);
  String girlsnight = table.getString(3, 1);
  String backstage = table.getString(4, 1);
  String ootd = table.getString(5, 1);
  String melbourne = table.getString(6, 1);
  String sydney = table.getString(7, 1);
  String emergingdesigner = table.getString(8, 1);
  String fashiongram = table.getString(9, 1);
  String foodblogger = table.getString(10, 1);
  String hiphop = table.getString(11, 1);
  String muji = table.getString(12, 1);
  String monochrome = table.getString(13, 1);
  String swag = table.getString(14, 1);
  String alannahhill = table.getString(15, 1);
  String popsofcolour = table.getString(16, 1);
  String stylesketch = table.getString(17, 1);
  String artist = table.getString(18, 1);
  String designer = table.getString(19, 1);
  String model = table.getString(20, 1);
  String vogue = table.getString(21, 1);
  String knitwear = table.getString(22, 1);
  String knitting = table.getString(23, 1);

  color workd = unhex("FF" + work);
  fill(workd);
  noStroke();
  rect(50, 50, 100, 100);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I think you really need to learn about `for` loops. Going through that table should only take a couple lines of code. [Here](https://processing.org/reference/for.html) is a link to the `for` loop reference.

Next, I'd recommend checking out [the `unhex()` reference](https://processing.org/reference/unhex_.html):

```java
String hs = "FF006699";
int hi = unhex(hs);
fill(hi);
rect(30, 20, 55, 55);
```

Other than that, you need to be much more specific about exactly what you're confused about. What about the `unhex()` function isn't working how you expect?

Comment: First, thanks for responding.
I've added how I thought the unhex() worked but it didn't, what am I missing?
Apologies for the inadequacy.

Comment: @lilibet What exactly does that code do? What exactly do you mean when you say it didn't work?

Comment: Basically, I have another sketch I made in processing that's a little revolving animation.
However, what I have to do now is get the  "Tag" names and it's corresponding value e.g. 'fashion' '299EC7' from the table and have them become a a colour palette. So I can call on any of these tag names and have them be colours.
e.g.   color[] pal1 = {fashion, blogger, artist, vogue, ootd};

Comment: @lilibet Why are you calling the `substring()` function?

Comment: I was overcomplicating it all, it's very late and I'm a beginner are my only excuses. Well now I feel incredibly silly.
You did mention above how `for` loops could help condense the table, I get that I could use something like: `for (int i = 0; i < 24; i = i+1)` but I don't know what I would put after that? or if that's even right?

Comment: @lilibet No problem, we've all been there. Does this mean you fixed your problem?

Comment: @lilibet No problem! Happy Coding!